# How can I print a full reference using reftex?

Tags: reftex-mode

I would like to embedd full references of BibTeX entries in selected sections of my org-mode files or at least have the ability to quickly open the full reference in a new buffer.

How can I do that?

`C-c &` (`reftex-view-crossref`) does not work and only opens an empty buffer when using the following configuration for reftex:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'org
  (defun org-mode-reftex-setup ()
    ;; (load-library "reftex")
    (require 'reftex)
    (and (buffer-file-name)
         (file-exists-p (buffer-file-name))
          (reftex-parse-all)
         )
        (make-local-variable 'reftex-cite-format)
    (setq reftex-cite-format "[[%l]]")
    (setq reftex-default-bibliography '("references"))
    (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c )") 'reftex-citation))
  (add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'org-mode-reftex-setup))
```

[1] [Reftex manual: Viewing cross references](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/reftex.html#Viewing-Cross_002dReferences)